# How to implement regular queue using priority queue?

Tags: algorithm

How to implement regular queue using priority queue?.
Also I need to find the running time of "enqueue" an "dequeue" in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a running index that remembers how many inserts were made, the `i`th element that was inserted, will have priority `i`. You are always polling the "lowest" priority element, which is the oldest one in the queue, as desired.

The time complexity, assuming you are using a "black box" priority queue is `O(logn)` for `popHead()` and `insert()`, and `O(1)` for `top()`. You might be able to tweak it to do the insertions and deletions faster if you don't assume "black box", but than again, if you can tweak it - just make it a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), or some other data structure that is optimized to be a queue.

Comment: If you assume that the prioqueue is implemented as a binary heap or a pairing heap, insert should be `O(1)`, too.

Comment: @phimuemue That's going to assume a specific implementation, as I specifically mentioned - I am assuming a black box here, because the OP did not ask for a specific implementation, he asked about the ADT "Priority Queue", and not on the specific "Binary heap" DS.

Comment: True, I just wanted to add it as supplementary information.

Answer (score 0):

***Assumptions with respect to Approach 1***

1. K is the key associated with all queue element
2. K is global variable
3. Decrease-key(Q,item,K)
   will decrease the global key value 'K'
   by 1 and associate the new 'K' value
   with the 'item'

***Approach 1***

*ENQUE(Q, item) *

```
Insert(Q, item) 
Decrease-key(Q, item, K)
```

*DE QUE(Q)*

```
item=Extract-Max(Q)
```

***Approach 2***

*ENQUE (Q, ITEM) *

```
Insert(Q, item) 
Increase-key(Q, item, k)
```

DE QUE (Q)

```
Item= Extract-Min(Q)
```

***Running time***

1. Enqueue - O(1)
2. Dequeue - Log(h)  where h is height of the binary heap

***NOTE***

1. Approach 1 - K will be monotonic
   decreasing
2. Approach 2 - K will be monotonic
   increasing

***Inspired from CLRS book***